# Edit csv file with Excel without reformatting in android

Tags: android, excel, csv, format

I'm trying to make a simple android app that basically imports a csv and inserts it to customised Array list. So far, I was able to read a csv file when I had not updated CSV file content.I found when I update CSV file with excel it  change the formate of csv file.
       Here is my code for reading csv file:

```
     selectedFile = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH));
         ArrayList<Expense> objList= new ArrayList<>();
       String file=selectedFile.getPath();

      FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
      try {
             fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedFile.getPath()));
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                        }


        BufferedReader reader = null;
     reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

             String line = "";
                        StringTokenizer st = null;
                        try {

                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                                ExpenseShare obj= new ExpenseShare ();
                                //your attributes
                                obj.setAmount(st.nextToken());
                                obj.setName(st.nextToken());
                                obj.setDate(st.nextToken());
                                obj.setTime(st.nextToken());
                                objList.add(obj);

                                Log.e("latasingh"," "+obj.getName()+" "+(obj.getAmount())+" "+obj.getDate()+" "+ obj.getTime()); //I understood this problem by seeing log data.
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

How can I resolved this problem.
Thank You !!

Comment: Please show a csv file before and after.

Comment: @greenapps ,I have update question.

Comment: what do u mean column sequence? because as i see both before and after have same column order, amount, date, name, time ?

Comment: `I have update question.` ?? A csv file is a text file. You should have showed us two pieces of text. Not a picture of how one or other app or program displays the files.

Comment: @Yazan when i read the file and  saving data line by line in  arraylist after that I fetch value of arraylist.get(i).getname(). it is returning value of date.So, I found it change sequence internal while store value in array list.Please help